# Not able to retrieve the app object from global space

Tags: javascript, jquery, marionette

I added two files to my index.html like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Marionette</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
    <script src="js/initApp.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my routes.js file:

```
    (function(){
    Social = window.Social || {};
    Social.Routes = Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize:function(){
            console.log('from routes');
        }
    });
}());
```

app.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    Social = window.App || {};
    Social.App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    Social.App.addInitializer(function(){
        console.log(Social);
    });

    Social.App.start();
});
```

initApp.js

```
(function(){
    Social = window.Social || {};
}())
```

I understand that, the way what i adding to global space is wrong here.. any one correct to add my variable to globally?

do i required to add a separate file before to these to files to make the app available to all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the minute you're just *hiding* the existing `window.Social` variable. You could easily have accessed it without the extra assignment. The correct way would be to pass `window.Social` in through the closure:

```
(function(social){
    social.mySocial = function() {

    };
}(window.Social));
```

Ensuring `window.Social` exists can be done either via an external JS file if you can be sure your file will be loaded in order, otherwise you will need to do `window.Social || (window.Social = {});` each time.

[Have a read here](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) for some namespacing patterns.